# How to remove empty space after animating a relative layout? [ANDROID]

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

i am animating a relative layout on scroll of recycler view. that relative layout contains a view pager. the animation works fine but after animation there is an empty space on top of recycler view. how to solve this?
here is my code any help will be appreciated

```
private int layout_height;
myrecyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    if (dy > 0) {
        // Scroll Down
            layout_height+= dy;
            sliderlayout.animate().translationY(-layout_height).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
    } else if (dy < 0) {
        // Scroll Up
            sliderlayout.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();

    }

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use sliderlayout.requestLayout() will make the whole layout rendering